# How do I use ng-repeat when the dynamic key value is an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my controller , i have the data like...

```
    data = {
        chartTypes":["pie","donut","bar","line"],
        "features":{
            "stacked": ["true","true","true","false"],
            "percentage":["false","false","true","false"]
         }
    };

$scope.docStructure = data
```

Is there any way that i can user ng-repeat to iterate over the keys and again iterate if the value is an array?

```
<div ng-app="chartFeatures" ng-controller="chartFeaturesCtrl" style="height:200px; background:red;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th ng-repeat="chartType in docStructure.chartTypes">{{chartType}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="(feature,supportedList) in docStructure.features">
            <td>{{feature}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="supported in supportedList">{{supported}}</td>
        </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

The ideas is I wanted to do a cross tab as below.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Error: ngRepeat:dupes. Duplicate Key in Repeater

Comment: Do not repeat over primitive types! It's bad practice. If you must though, add `track by $index` to all ng repeats

Comment: @Mike why is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `track by $index` to the ng-repeat on the td tag

```
<td ng-repeat="supported in supportedList track by $index">{{supported}}</td>
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/xejudapo/1/edit)

You could also convert your "features" arrays to contain objects instead of primitives, and then you don't need the `track by $index`

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/nawageke/1/edit) of that.